# Is there an R function for applying Simplex algorithm from a given feasible starting point?

Tags: r

I would like to start Simplex algorithm from a feasible point apart from the origin.

Is there any suitable function for this problem in R? I've tried the packages lpSolve and lpSolveAPI.